# are you missing a cast?

Tags: .net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'DoctorFront.Models.DocMaster' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
namespace DoctorFront.Controllers
{
    public class DoctorController : ApiController
    {
        static readonly IDocRepositories Repository  =new DocRepositories();
        public IEnumerable GetAllDoctor()
        {
            return Repository.GetAll();
        }

        public IEnumerable GetDoctor(int id) 
        {

            return Repository.Get(id);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that your `GetDoctor` method is meant to return `DocMaster`, right?

Comment: change the return type to something like `DocMaster`.

Comment: Yes it returns doc master table

Comment: thankzz  @Amit Kumar Ghosh It worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable GetDoctor(int id) 
{

    return Repository.Get(id); // problem here
}
```

Your method `GetDoctor` is supposed to return an object of type IEnumerable.  Your return statement is only returning a *single* `DocMaster` object.

So this should work:

```
public DocMaster GetDoctor(int id) 
{

    return Repository.Get(id);
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As you need to do on any method, your return must match the method declaration. So if you have a method `public IEnumerable Get(int id)`, you'll need to return a any class that implements `IEnumerable`.

The example BviLLe_Kid gave shows its correct correction to stop receiving this error.

Here is a more complete example:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id) 
{
    var doc = Repository.Get(id);

    if (doc == null)
        return NotFound();

    return Ok(doc);
}
```

If you are working with `Web API`, it's good to read about [rest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)